# Checkerboard. How to alternate squares?

Tags: python, processing

Trying to create a checkerboard with alternating white and black squares. This code keeps coming up with an error and cannot find the solution or how to have the code appear on the canvas.

the error code is "mismatched input '\n' expecting COLON

```
x = 10   
y = 10      
sq_size = 20    

def setup ():
    background (150)


for i in range(8):
    for n in range(8): 
        fill (255)
            if i + n % 2 == 0
    else:
        fill (0)
        rect(x + i * sq_size, y + n *sq_size, sq_size, sq_size)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You need to be more specific here.

Comment: You're having a `else` which is not after an `if`

Comment: @MaximeB `else` is valid after a `for` loop -- it means "if the loop ran to completion and did not break early, run this code".  (Granted, it seems like that is not what the questioner intended here.)

Comment: @Rabbid76: [Here is a version of that documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) that is *not* seventeen years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That if statement is in the wrong place.  Try something like this:

```
x = 10   
y = 10      
sq_size = 20    

def setup ():
    size(200,200)
    background (150)

def draw():
    for i in range(8):
        for n in range(8): 
            if (i + n) % 2 == 0:
                fill (255)    
            else:
                fill (0)
            rect(x + i * sq_size, y + n *sq_size, sq_size, sq_size)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now, did not realize my if statement was in the wrong place.